# eclipse needs legacy Java SE 6

Tags: java, eclipse

I updated my mac to Yosemite 10.10.
Now it gives me this error:

```
To open “Eclipse.app” you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime.
```

What should I do?

Comment: I tested that approach. That doesn't work :(

Comment: Do you have installed the legacy Java SE 6 runtime? 64 bits or 32 bits version? If so, what is the path?

Comment: Also, look the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563766/eclipse-kepler-for-os-x-mavericks-request-java-se-6

Comment: It works well before updating my mac.

Comment: I don't know what do you need but as i think you need this: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents

Comment: So, your jdk is 1.7. See the accepted anser on the link I just gave you

Comment: Thanks a lot. I restart my pc and it work with that manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java JDK 1.6 is not installed on your computer.

You probably installed Java JDK 1.7 or 1.8 before the Yosemite update.

If you don't want to install JRE6 at all and simply use JRE7 or JRE8 without symlinking it to the JRE6 either you can do the following solution as described by Nikolas Grottendieck [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19594116/837765).

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to install JDK1.6. I am repeating my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433495/intellij-not-starting-after-os-x-yosemite-update/31231728#31231728).

edit Info.plist file, in your jdk, for example:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Info.plist
```

update JVMCapabilities dictionary to have following values:

```
          <key>JVMCapabilities</key>
            <array>
                    <string>CommandLine</string>
                    <string>JNI</string>
                    <string>BundledApp</string>
                    <string>WebStart</string>
                    <string>Applets</string>
            </array>
```