# IntelliJ IDEA can't open projects or add SDK on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, intellij-14, macos-catalina

If I open IntelliJ IDEA and try and import any project or open any folder containing a project, nothing happens, I'm just returned to this screen.

[image]

Earlier on, before I moved my project files around, I tried to set a new JDK for a project and i clicked add SDK and then selected Java 12 home and again it returned to the screen without adding anything.

Is there some permission I need to grant to IntelliJ Idea?

Seems to have started since installing MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219856) specific to the recent macOS Catalina update. Please follow YouTrack ticket for updates.

You can also help by providing the following information in YouTrack:

Open the file chooser, select a directory (but don't open it yet), take a screenshot, then open a directory; then attach [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) and the screenshot (a path to a project and a time of the operation are needed, too, but they should be guessable from the screenshot).

As a workaround until this issue is resolved you can add `-Dide.mac.file.chooser.native=false` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart the IDE.

Comment: The workaround doesn't work for me (macOS 10.15.1, Goland 2019.2.5). I gave Goland full disk access as a temporary fix.

Comment: Same here, macOS 12.0.1, IDEA 2021.2.3 @FarshidT

Answer (score 7):

Mac OS, Mojave or Catalina,
Exit intellij first,

1. Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click Privacy.
2. Click the lock , then enter your administrator password.
3. From the list of items on the left, select Full Disk Access.
4. Add Intellij(or other whatever app having this problem) to the apps allowed full-disk access by using the add button.

Lock and try again.

Hope this will help.

Ref from apple support of other things, but I tried, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I can temporarily open things by dragging a folder to that window it seems, but its' not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem after the (PyCharm) update. Workaround: Go back to the old version.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858297/7024760