# Android Studio Can't Open Existing Projects

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, webstorm, macos-catalina

I cant open any of my existing projects on android studio for some reason, I can create a new project but any time i try and open an exiting one it opens the file finder i click on the project and nothing happens.

Ive tried invalidating and clearing cache, uninstalling all plugin, deleting, re-downloading and re-installing but nothing seems to be working

Im running macOS Catalina 10.15 and Android Studio 3.4.2

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkjkb.jpg)

Comment: are you sure that you are selecting the correct folder ? can you show a screenshot when selecting the project folder ?

Comment: @Psycho Even if he did select the "wrong" folder then it would still open something.

Comment: @Bolu Do you know if Android Studio is optimized for macOS Catalina? (I use macOS Mojave - it's working fine.)

Comment: @Psycho Yes i am, I've tried opening multiple projects but none are working

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException Im thinking thats the issue, but ive been using it on Catalina for like a month now with no issues

Comment: @Bolu Did you recently upgrade the macOS or the Android Studio first? Did this just start happening?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException nope i didn't upgrade either recently, I was using it this morning and i was trying to build a signed APK, when i tried selecting the store key  with finder ill click and nothing will happen so i invalidated cache restarted deleted all my recent projects and now none of them are opening again.

Comment: @Bolu OK - I'm not sure what's happening. I would try a downgrade to the macOS (to a stable Mojave version) but I'll upvote this to get more people to look.

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException Thanks alot for your time

Comment: @Bolu Before I completely give up - have you tried a fresh install of Android Studio?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException Yes that, was the last thing i tried before i came here. Deleted the old one, downloaded a new one and installed but the issue still persisted

Comment: @Bolu OK. Are you going to try the downgrade? If yes then tell me if it works again. if you don't... well then you'll just have to wait for somebody who knows the answer to come by.

Comment: Have you tried both 'Open' and 'New->Import project'?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException yes, why?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Because then you know that he tried to create a new project and open an existing one.

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException yes but my question still stands. Did they try to open by using the File->open or New-> import project. I don't ask about creating a completely new project, but opening an existing one through importing it

Comment: @NikosHidalgo The OP tried deleting their projects and taking them back from github - and before that the OP tried File -> Open

Comment: @NikosHidalgo yes i did try Importing but that didn't work either

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException I downgraded back to macOS Mojave and everything is working fine now thanks

Comment: Facing same issue with macOS Catalina, waiting for Android Studio update or quick fix :/

Comment: @Bolu This was my solution, mind letting me add it? (And delete yours...) :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004341740-IDEA-2019-2-doesn-t-open-old-projects

Adding

> -Dide.mac.file.chooser.native=false

to .vmoptions helps.

Comment: This answer works for me. I can also confirm that it works with compare dialog for file compare.

Comment: Android Studio 4.?.? it doesn't even open anymore...

Answer (score 9):

Just to summarise (and make it clear) there are 3 different options to solve this.

1. From within Android Studio if you can open it...

   - Click the menu item Help->Edit Custom VM Options...
   - In the editor studio.vmoptions that opens up, add the following, save and restart Android Studio

```
-Dide.mac.file.chooser.native=false
```

2. Via Mac OS X Terminal window, type

```
open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app "path to your project"
```

You can get the path to your project by going into the project directory and typing,

```
pwd
```

3. From Mac OS X Finder

   - locate the folder for the Android Studio project that you want to open.
   - drag the folder to the Android Studio App (from Applications or from the Dock if it is there)

Answer (score 4):

There is something wrong with `androdi studio` in `macOS Catalina`, so you can not open exist project or import project in `android studio`. But as **an alternative**, you can open project in command line, like below

```sh
$ open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app "path to your project"
```

Answer (score 4):

See my answer at, 
[IntelliJ IDEA can't open projects or add SDK on macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361503/intellij-idea-cant-open-projects-or-add-sdk-on-macos-catalina/58551319#58551319), I think it also works for Android studio.

Mac OS, Mojave or Catalina, Exit Android studio first,

- Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click Privacy.
- Click the lock, then enter your administrator password.
- From the list of items on the left, select Full Disk Access.
- Add Android studio(or other whatever app having this problem) to the apps allowed full-disk access by using the add button.

Lock and try again.

I hope this will help.

Ref from apple support of other things, but I tried, it works!

Comment: Sorted my problem on MacOS Big Sur + Android Studio 4.1

Answer (score 3):

Drag the project folder and drop on Android studio icon in the dock to open the project. Since its beta we have to wait for a fix from Apple or Jetbrains.

Comment: WOW. This worked and thanks. This was driving me nuts. 3.6 under Catalina, crashing on launch

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 3.4.2 is probably not optimized for macOS Catalina. Try downgrading to macOS Mojave. It's what I use and it's working fine.

Stay clear of beta versions - not everyone develops against beta versions.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a late response. This answer is for having issues with 4.x not launching on macOS after upgrade or uninstall and reinstall.

`rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio{PREVIOUS_VERSION}`

Example: `rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories